# ffmpeg concat + invalid data found when processing + check for valid avi file

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm using ffmpeg to concatenate (merge) multiple avi files to a single avi file.
I'm using the following command.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy out.avi
```

The list of files to merge is given in mylist.txt

```
Ex 'mylist.txt':
 file 'v01.avi'
 file 'v02.avi'
 file 'v03.avi'
...
 file 'vxx.avi'
```

However, there is a problem when one of the file is corrupted (or empty).
In this case, the video only contains the files up to the corrupted file.

In this case, ffmpeg return the following errors:

```
[concat @ 02b2ac80] Impossible to open 'v24.avi'
mylist.txt: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Q1) Is there a way to tell ffmpeg to continue merging even if it encounters an invalid file ?

Alternatively, I decided to write a batch file that check if my avi files are valid before doing the merging.
My second problem is that this operation takes more time that doing the merging itself.

Q2) Is there a fast way to check if multiple avi files are valid with ffmpeg ? (and delete, ignore or rename them if they are not valid).

Thanks in advance for your comments.

ssinfod.

For information, here is my current DOS batch file. (This batch is working but very slow because of the ffprobe to check if my avi are valids)

GO.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
echo.
echo == MERGING STARTED ==
echo.
set f=C:\myfolder
set outfile=output.avi
set listfile=mylist.txt
set count=1

if exist %listfile% call :deletelistfile
if exist %outfile% call :deleteoutfile

echo == Checking if avi is valid (with ffprobe) ==
for %%f in (*.avi) DO (
    call ffprobe -v error %%f
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo "ERROR:Corrupted file"
        move %%f %%f.bad
        del %%f
    )
)

echo == List avi files to convert in listfile ==
for %%f in (*.avi) DO (
    echo file '%%f' >> %listfile%
    set /a count+=1
)
ffmpeg -v error -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy %outfile%
echo.
echo == MERGING COMPLETED ==
echo.
GOTO :EOF

:deletelistfile
 echo "Deleting mylist.txt"
 del %listfile%
GOTO :EOF

:deleteoutfile
 echo "Deleting output.avi"
 del %outfile%
GOTO :EOF

:EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that `ffmpeg` terminates with an exit value greater 0 if any error occurred during operation. I don't have `ffmpeg` installed and therefore can't verify it.

So I would suppose that all AVI files in the list are valid on first run of `ffmpeg` for concatenation. Then check the return code assigned to `errorlevel`.

If the return code is 0, the concatenation of all AVI files was successful and batch can be exited.

Otherwise the more time consuming code is used to find out which AVI files are not valid, sort them out and concatenate the remaining AVI files.

So the batch file could be something like below (not tested):

```
@echo off
set "ListFile=%TEMP%\mylist.txt"
set "OutputFile=output.avi"

:PrepareMerge
if exist "%ListFile%" call :DeleteListFile
if exist "%OutputFile%" call :DeleteOutputFile

echo == List avi files to convert into list file ==
for %%F in (*.avi) do echo file '%%~fF'>>"%ListFile%"
if not exist "%ListFile%" goto CleanUp

echo == Merge the avi files to output file ==
ffmpeg.exe -v error -f concat -i "%ListFile%" -c copy "%OutputFile%"
if not errorlevel 1 goto Success

echo.
echo =================================================
echo ERROR: One or more avi files are corrupt.
echo =================================================
echo.

echo == Checking which avi are valid (with ffprobe) ==
for %%F in (*.avi) do (
    ffprobe.exe -v error "%%~fF"
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo Corrupt file: %%~nxF
        ren "%%~fF" "%%~nF.bad"
    )
)
goto PrepareMerge

:DeleteListFile
echo Deleting list file.
del "%ListFile%"
goto :EOF

:DeleteOutputFile
echo Deleting output file.
del "%OutputFile%"
goto :EOF

:Success
echo == MERGING COMPLETED ==
call :DeleteListFile

:CleanUp
set "ListFile="
set "OutputFile="
```

`if not errorlevel 1` means if errorlevel is NOT greater or equal 1 which means is 0 (or negative).

Comment: It is a good idea to try merging first and deal with errors only if they are present. I will try it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In mylist.txt, you have to remove 'file' at the beginning of the line because the code you use echoing "file" yet before calling the line of your text file